# Why is my shape warping on this bezier curve?

Tags: bezier-curves, curve-modifier

I'm trying to take a flat rectangular shape and bend it along a curve so that it looks almost like a rainbow. I'm following the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHkzyH9dpv4), which has me following these basic steps:

1. Create lots of edges along the shape (using loop cut) so that it has something to bend along
2. Create the bezier curve
3. Position the origins of both the curve and the shape at the edge of each
4. Use a curve modifier

But when I follow these steps, my shape gets really fat in the middle.

[image: Before applying curve modifier]
[image: After applying curve modifier]

How do I get it so that the shape maintains a uniform width while bending along the bezier curve?

Any advice would be really helpful! Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe make sure that the curve vertices radius are set to one (select curve, switch to Edit mode, select a vertex and check its radius in the N panel)

Comment: I agree. You can also use ALT-S to scale the thickness with a point selected.